# How to use Angular 2 (or 4) framework from CDN

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 1.x we had the option of linking to Angular framework using a CDN (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js).  Is that option available in Angular 2?

Comment: Wasn't hard to find this: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angularjs

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17

Comment: https://angularcdn.com/

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix No it was.

Answer (score 5):

You can try a CDN like [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/)

Load System JS and ES6:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```

[Example with plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXOGwX8bW0AYc86OgVdQ?p=preview)

[Example with JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/angulartypescript/n305zyya/)

Comment: This is for an old beta version (2.0.0 beta). How to get it working for the later versions?