# Angular 2 from a CDN

Tags: angular, cdn, codepen

I want to create a Code Pen using Angular 2, latest version (6.2.2 according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli).

I would like to load Angular from a CDN and fail to find versions `> 2.0.0-beta` anywhere.

E.g. there is a pen [here](https://codepen.io/mikkokam/pen/BjJPoX) that references Angular version 2.0.0-beta.13 from this URL:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.min.js
```

Why are there no hosted versions of Angular `> 2.0.0-beta`? What am I missing?

Comment: Also see [How to use Angular 2 (or 4) framework from CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868701/how-to-use-angular-2-or-4-framework-from-cdn)

Comment: Angular has a complex build system that requires more than can be provided by simply including .js files. If you want to run something in an online environment, consider using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).